# users suddenly cannot login to asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, iis-7

My asp.net application was working fine with a few users using Membership provider. Suddenly the passwords don't work. This happened a couple of times before when I was in the developing stage, and ignored it and made new test users. Any idea what triggers this? I am using visual studio 2010.

BTW, this may be related to another problem that arose at the same time.. I posted the question here: [Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351289/web-deployment-task-failed-the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-web-deployment-d)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both questions are horribly vague and would be nearly impossible to diagnosis without more information.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that these errors started after my computer froze and I had to restart, and that the properties page was unsaved in visual studio. And here's the complete output for the other error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3588,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)
Publish failed to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Membership provider lock user access if he inserts wrong password 5 times.

Is this the situation?

[Asp.net Membership - Accounts getting locked out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1876921/735864)

Comment: Agree with danyolgiax +1. Many of the issues I had when I first used the Membership provider had to do with the configuration. Check the web.config and make sure you have the lock parameters and session time set they way you want.

Comment: The first time I take an hour to realize that the reason my user wasn't able to login the application was that in my database there was the lockedout flag setted! :-(

Comment: I did get locked out, but I set the 'IsLockedOut' field back to '0' in the database, and still can't login.

Comment: Are you getting an ASP error message when you try to log in or is it saying the login is incorrect?

Comment: It says "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again." I'm not sure if that's an ASP error. It looks like preset error message you would get for invalid credentials.

Comment: That is a generic message. This page may help you put in some code to find out exactly way the login fails. [How to Add Errors to a Login Control](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/howto-errors-login-asp4-csharp.aspx) Also, make sure the isApproved field in the db is also set to true.

Comment: I think I figured it out: the users clicked on "Forgot Password?" I don't have the email part set up yet, so they don't get emails saying what the new password is, but I guess that PasswordRecovery control changes it for you anyway. Just a couple of users. I'll set up the email and hope it works then. Thanks for all your help anyway!!